# Why a PHP warning appearing in Chrome but not in any other browser?

Tags: php

I'm writing a web application in PHP, and I'm getting the following warning *in Google Chrome only:*

> **Warning:** Cannot use a scalar value as an array in
>   **M:\xampp\htdocs\MyProjectTitle\php\classes.php** on line **18**

Background: Please note that the web app works just fine in all browsers I tested (Firefox, Chrome, IE), but the warning appearing in Chrome is bugging the hell outta me.

Notes: I have tried restarting Chrome and clearing the Chrome cache. I have tried restarting the computer. I have tried searching the source code in FF and IE to see if the warning was just hidden, but to no avail. The warning is only popping up in Google Chrome, and I have no idea why.

UPDATE: Even though Safari also uses WebKit, it does not show the PHP warning. For some reason, Chrome is the only one that has the PHP warning. Weird stuff!

UPDATE: Here's the first 21 lines of code:

```
class Presenter {
    public function includeFile($filePath) {
        if (is_readable($filePath)) {
            include $filePath;
        } else {
            echo '<p><strong>ERROR 404</strong></p>';
            echo '<p>The resource you requested could not be located.</p>';
        }
    }

    public function sanitize($string) {
        return preg_replace("/\s/","_",$string);
    }

    public function set($varname,$value) {
        $this->$varname = $value;
        $_SESSION[$this->name][$varname] = $value;

        return $this;   // enables chaining!
    }

    // And there's more code after this, but I have cut it out here.
}
```

Note: The above code is inside a PHP class.

UPDATE: I know exactly what lines of code are causing the warning in Chrome (although I still have no clue why Chrome is the only browser that shows the warning). Since my webapp works perfectly despite the warning in Chrome, I have used `@` to suppress the warnings in Chrome (I'll fix the warning later).

Comment: Post `M:\xampp\htdocs\MyProjectTitle\php\classes.php` code please.

Comment: Did you try holding CTRL and then hitting F5 so the cache is refreshed? Since PHP is server-side I'm not sure what can cause this, unless Chrome sends some strange headers or something.

Comment: @JOHN I would, but it is a lot of code. I'm just looking for an explanation as to why it is even possible for PHP to kick a warning out in Chrome only. :)

Comment: Have you viewed the source of the page(on other browsers) on which this error appears and searched for the error message, maybe the error is just hidden.

Comment: @Devator Yes, I tried that and I tried restarting my computer, but to no avail (I'm using XAMPP).

Comment: @Ravi Yes, I have tried searching through the source code as well, but the warning only appears in Google Chrome.

Comment: So what does line 18 say? Or could you give us an minimized version of your script?

Comment: I think just first 18 lines would be far enough.

Comment: `Cannot use a scalar value as an array`.  Try to check `is_array($var)` before line 18.  If it's not an array, make it one.  Where is that variable coming from?  Maybe Chrome is sending different POST/GET data.

Comment: @Devator and JOHN: okay, I have included the first 19 lines of the code. I hope that helps! :)

Comment: Another interesting point: does this warning also show in Safari?  Safari and Chrome use the same underlying engine.  If Safari doesn't display an error, then the issue is client-side with Chrome; if it does, then something's odd with WebKit.

Comment: Did you `session_start()` before trying to access `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @Rocket: Yes, I put `session_start()` at the very beginning of my script.

Comment: @Aleks G: That's a very good idea! I don't have Safari on my system right now, but I'll install it and tell you guys what happens. :)

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** it's **first** 19 lines of code? It uses `$this`, so it should be placed inside the class, but I can see no class declaration in code you posted. You declare class in one file and have it's definition in another?

Comment: Is it possible that you've put anything else in `$_SESSION[$this->name]` at some other point of your script? It's unlikely caused by browser itself.

Comment: @Aleks G: Interesting! I installed Safari for Windows. When I ran my webapp in Safari, it does not show the PHP warning! This is really weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I know exactly what lines of code are causing the warning in Chrome (although I still have no clue why Chrome is the only browser that shows the warning...**If you know, please let me know!**). Since my webapp works perfectly despite the warning in Chrome, I have used `@` to suppress the warning as a temporary fix until I can fix it for real later.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it's this:

```
$_SESSION[$this->name][$varname] = $value;
```

if `$_SESSION[$this->name]` was not defined as an array earlier, you'll get the "can't use scalar as array" error. e.g. if you do

```
$_SESSION[$this->name] = 42;
$_SESSION[$this->name][$varname] = 'will not work';
```

the error is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that Chrome sends different data to the server, therefore you are having this error. If there's **any** $_POST data, or $_GET data please verify that with what other browsers send. You can easily display the contents using `print_r()` or `var_dump()` whichever you choose.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because you do something browser-specific(maybe you do something IE specific, and firerfox-specific, but forgot to add a "default" case for other browsers?)

Comment: How do you suppose to do some *browser specific* in **server code**?

Comment: by using $_SERVER['user-agent']...:)

Answer (score 1):

Basically that is happening because you are trying to access a UNDEFINED variable (or not set variable).

PHP omits MANY common programming mistakes, that other languajes don't permit.

Ok if you start a program like:

```
<?php if(eregi("hi",$hello)) { echo "hi"; } ?>
```

Will get this "message"
Notice: Undefined variable: hello in C:\var\www\test.php on line 1

you sould predefined it as:
    `<?php $hello = "hello"; if(eregi("hi",$hello)) { echo "hi"; } ?>`

Or a conditioned to avoid elimination of previous values:
    `$hello = isset($hello) ? $hello : null;`

This code will send you a deprecated function message also.

any why this messages are caused by the PHP.INI configuration on your server, this is happening because you had something like this:

display_error = on;
error_reporting = E_ALL;

And sould be something like:

display_error = on;
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT

This will remove all NOTICES messages and make PHP more permisive, also you can add ~E_DEPRECATED if you get deprecated messages,

**how ever getting this messages, means that you need to be a more secitive programmer! Yes is more tediuos but some one has to make it!**

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you need to do ctr+f5 or restart in your other browser. It probably has a previous version of your page cached, happened to me a lot with Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tim Fennis, but I have tried that (and restarting my computer) but to no avail. The warning is persistently appearing in Google Chrome only.